# In Schmidt process, how to express original vectors over newly computed orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

As you can see in this picture, this is Gram-Schmidt process which produces **u** and **e** using **a**. I cannot understand how it express **a** over **e**(orthonormal basis)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space endowed with a vector product. If $(e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then, for each vector $v\in V$,$$v=\langle v,e_1\rangle e_1+\langle v,e_2\rangle e_2+\cdots+\langle v,e_n\rangle e_n.\tag1$$But, in your specific situation, each $e_k$ is a linear combination of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$. It follows from this that each $a_k$ is a linear combination of $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_k$. Therefore, in $(1)$, if $v=a_k$, then $\langle v,a_m\rangle=0$ if $m>k$. SO, you get that$$a_k=\langle a_k,e_1\rangle e_1+\langle a_k,e_2\rangle e_2+\cdots+\langle a_k,e_k\rangle e_k.$$

Comment: So you means that:$a_k=c_1e_1+c_2e_2+...+c_ke_k (k\in\{1,2,\dots,n\})$ thus $⟨a_k,e_m⟩=⟨c_1e_1+c_2e_2+\dots+c_ke_k,e_m⟩=c_1⟨e_1,e_m⟩+c_2⟨e_2,e_m⟩+\dots+c_2⟨e_k,e_m⟩$ and because $⟨e_i,e_j⟩=0(i\not\neq j)$ so $$⟨a_k,e_m⟩=0 (m>k) $$. Can I understand in this way?

Comment: Yes, that's fine (except that the last $c_2$ should be $c_m$).